How to create a database with "Dual" mode in Analysis Services Tabular?
I want to create a database in Analysis Services Tabular 2022 (compatibilityLevel: 1600) in c# using the TOM Api (tabular object model)  but I can't
I can create the database in Import mode, and also in DirectQuery mode... but in Dual mode NO.
Actually, I can create it but then when I try create the tables I have an error that I don't understand
For example:

I create the dual database (ok)
Then I create a table in Import mode (ok)
Then I create a table in Direct Query mode... but in this moment I have this error:

Partitions that contain a full dataset (not sampled data) have to be configured for DirectQuery and Full DataViews, or use Import query mode to retrieve data. This model appears to have partitions that are non-compliant. Please check partition configuration.

Please share the code you've tried.

Theoretically, can I create the example I mentioned?

All in c#:
(1) I create the database using defaultMode = Dual. --->
(2) Then, I create my tables using the ModeType in the partition = DirectQuery or Import.
(I have only 1 partition by table)
